# Packed Bubble Chart with Gradient Legend in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, legend, gradient

We are using the packed bubble chart but we are using the size AND color to represent the same data dimension (e.g. money each person has)[image]

Functionally, the color is on a gradient from low to high. And now we would like to add in a legend kindof like what you have on a heat map (https://www.highcharts.com/demo/heatmap) where you can see the low color/value with a gradient to the high color/value. Your demo on the heatmap even has a sympathetic highlight between the cell and the legend... that would be cool to bring over. Hell, it would be super cool to even use the legend to filter or refine the circles!

Anyway. The core of the quesiton is, how can we bring that heatmap style legend into the packed bubble chart? Not the bubble size, but representing the color

Answer (score 0):

You need to use color axis. It is a separate module, but it is also build-in in heatmap and map.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    colorAxis: {
        ...
    },
    ...
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/smo3nfzj/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colorAxis